# Copy a range to a different sheet based on checkbox value or booelan value

Tags: google-apps-script, checkbox, return-value, spreadsheet, copy-paste

I need some help with my code. On my condition, I have 12 sheets based on the month calendar and I try to copy my data on a certain month to another "big data" sheet whenever the next month appears. I use a checkbox to trigger the function (copy monthly data) but the problem is the checkbox didn't work well. Every time I put my data it will copy to big data instantly and it was really confusing. I put my checkbox on cell E4 and the data that I intend to copy is on the range C:R to the last row.

```html
  function onEdit1(event){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Januari");
   if(s.getName() == "Januari" && r.getColumn() == 5 && r.getRow() == 4 && r.getValue() == true); {
   var range = sheet.getRange(13, 3, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 18);
   var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("REKAP JADWAL BULANAN PER 5 TAHUN");
   var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1,3);
    sheet.getRange(13, 3, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 18).copyTo(target);
   sheet.getRange(13, 3, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 18).clear({contentsOnly:true});  
  }
 }
```

[sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz73Y.png)

Comment: An `onEdit` function runs directly when the edit has been made - so when you check the checkbox. If this is not what you want, you will need to implement a time-based trigger. But can you first explain morein detail what you mean by "whenever the next month appears"? When exactly do you want the data to be copied?

Comment: And I believe `function onEdit1(event) {` should be `function onEdit(event) {` without `1` after `onEdit`

Comment: @ziganotschka, i have 12 sheets based on month's name. I want to trigger copy range to different sheet with time-based trigger. Ex : If this month is February so i want previous sheet, which is "January" is get copy to different sheet automatically

Comment: @YuriKhristich yes you're right, but i intend to add number after `onEdit` because i have more than one `onEdit` function

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the error is in this line:

```
if(s.getName() == "Januari" && r.getColumn() == 5 && r.getRow() == 4 && r.getValue() == true); {
```

You don't need `;` before `{`